# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data when ',' or ']' was expected

Tags: jquery, json, syntax-error

I created a cordova app, but i got an error show in the titel.

Here's my code snipped:

```
function parseIcs() {
   data = '{"journal":[],"timezone":[{"standard":[{"tzoffsetfrom":[{"value":"+0200","name":"TZOFFSETFROM","params":[]}]}]}';

   var json = $.parseJSON(data);

   console.log(json.timezone.standard.tzoffsetfrom.name);

}
```

I tried this code with my browser, there i read, that the problem is in the jquerymobile.js, but if I use the sample code from wikipedia's json site, it works.

do you have any ideas?

Comment: You have invalid JSON string

Comment: Missing `]}`. Any of a zillion online json validating sites would tell you this, e.g., http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Try http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a kind of IDE to spot what closing `]` or `}`s you have. Currently, you're missing `]}` at the end:

```
data = '{"journal":[],"timezone":[{"standard":[{"tzoffsetfrom":[{"value":"+0200","name":"TZOFFSETFROM","params":[]}]}]}]}';
```

That works just fine. If you would paste the code somewhere like the links posted in the comments: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ or http://jsonlint.com/, or even http://jsfiddle.net or a downloadable code editor that has syntax highlighting, it'll be easy to spot what brackets you still need to close.